# How to convert AIX timestamp of file to EPOCH

Tags: aix

I want to get the epoch date format on the file below:

```
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix   12247577 Jan 21 00:50 shop14_0_Log0001274968.Z
```

Using stat on the file I get the below file date information.

```
stat shop14_0_Log0001274968.Z
  File: shop14_0_Log0001274968.Z
  Size: 12247577        Blocks: 23928      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 800000640000000dh/9223372466351505421d  Inode: 410         Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (66001/informix)   Gid: ( 3000/informix)
Access: 2020-01-21 00:50:07.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2020-01-21 00:50:06.000000000 +0200
Change: 2020-01-21 00:50:08.000000000 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Is there a better command to pull date information on a file and use that to convert to epoch on AIX. If I can get the date information, what command will I use to do what I need to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use perl, an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

sub ftimestamp {
    my $fname= $_[0];
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
        $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
        = stat($fname);
    printf ("%-20s: atime=%d mtime=%d ctime=%d\n", $fname, $atime, $mtime, $ctime);
}

my $arg;

foreach $arg (@ARGV) {
    ftimestamp ($arg);
}
```